# VLOOKUP using data sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup

Based on a sample here:

3P  3RD PARTY RTU
AE  ACCESS CONTROL EQUIP
AH  ACCESS HATCHES
AI  AERIAL
BB  BHOLE PUMP MEC ELEC
BG  BUILD GENERAL ADMIN
BP  BST PUMPING MEC ELEC
BV  BOREHOLE SHAFT CIVIL
BX  BUILDING OPERATIONAL
CB  CIRCUIT BREAKER
CC  COMMS CONTROLLER
CI  CHAMBER
CM  COMPRESSOR
CY  CONTROL SYSTEMS
DB  DISTRIBUTION BOARDS
DL  Datalink
DO  Doors
DP  DOSING PUMPS
DU  DECONTAMINATION UNIT

How can I populate fields on another sheet using the above in a separate data sheet?

For example if I want the column to be populated with "BHOLE PUMP MEC ELEC" if BB is found in the column next to it.

Answer (score 0):

that's a bog standard Vlookup. If cell A1 contains "BB" and the table above is on Sheet2, then the formula is

=vlookup(a1,Sheet2!A1:B100,2,false)

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly! Expanding on this, how would I get it to mark up the cells in red that do not match the data sheet.

For example - if the Code is BB but the model has been incorrectly entered in as "Datalink". I'm guessing this involves Conditional Formatting but am unsure what formula this needs to take on.

Comment: That's a different question and should be in its own post. You can do that with conditional formatting. The exact techique depends on your Excel version if the stuff is on two different sheets.